# 2D array and pointer in C - how to access elements?

Tags: c, pointers

I have an example involving a pointer to a 2D array. Can someone help me understand what is going on in this example?

```
int main()
{

    int i = 0, j=0, sum0=0, sum1=0;
    int data[4][3] = { {23,55,50},{45,38,55},{70,43,45},{34,46,60}};
    int *Ptr;
    Ptr = *data;    //Why is the indirection operator used here? 
                    // Does Ptr = 23 by this assignment?

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        sum1 = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            sum1 += data[i][j];
        }
        if (sum1 > sum0) {
                 sum0 = sum1;
                 Ptr = *(data + i);     // Seems like this statement makes Ptr
        }                               // point one row below ... what syntax
    }                                   // can you use to access columns then?
                                       // Is it possible to use pointer arithmetic
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)                 // to access elements of data[i][j] that
        printf("%d\n", Ptr[i]);          // are not at j = 0?

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup! I was taking an intro CS course and this was just an example given from my lecture notes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`data` is a 2 dimentional array, which has 4 rows and each row has 3 elements (ie 4 X 3).

Now, `Ptr = *data;` means you are storing the starting address of 1st row to the pointer variable `Ptr`. This statement is equivalent to `Ptr = *(data + 0)`. `Ptr = *(data + 1)` - this means we are assigning 2nd row's starting address.

Then `*Ptr` or `*(Ptr + 0)` will give you the value of the first element of the row to which is pointing. Similarly, `*(Ptr + 1)` will give you the value of the second element of the row.

The `for` loop in your program is used to identify which row has the maximum value of the sum of its elements (3 elements). Once the control comes out of that `for` loop, `Ptr` will be pointing to the row which has the maximum sum of its elements and `sum0` will have the value of the sum.

Consider an array `int a[5];`, I hope you know that `a[0]` and `0[a]` is the same. This is because `a[0]` means `*(a+0)` and `0[a]` means `*(0 + a)`. This same logic can be used in 2 dimensional array.

`data[i][j]` is similar to `*(*(data + i) + j)`. We can write it as `i[data][j]` also.

For more details please refer to the book "Understanding Pointers in C" by Yashavant Kanetkar.

Answer (score 7):

`Ptr = *data;` is short for `*(data+0)+0` which is a pointer for first column element of the first row. the first 0 added with data is the row no., which is indirected and takes us to the first row. `* (data+0)` is still a address and not a value it points to (for 2D array). So, Ptr now points to the address of first column in first row. The second zero is the column no.. So, first row and first column's memory address is chosen. Using indirection (*) again would only now give value that the address holds. like `* (*(data+0)+0)` or `**data`.

Generally, if p is pointer name,i row number and j column number,

1. `(*(p+i)+j)` would give a memory address of a element in 2D array. i is row no. and j is col no.,
2. `*(*(p+i)+j)` would give the value of that element.
3. `*(p+i)` would access the ith row
4. to access columns, add column number to `*(p+i)`. You may have to declare the pointer as `(*p)[columns]` instead of just `*p`. Doing so, you are declaring pointer to an 2D array.

Using pointer arithmetic is treating 2d array like 1D array. Initialize pointer *Ptr to first element (`int *Ptr = *data`) and then add an no. (`Ptr + n`) to access the columns. Adding a number higher than column number would simply continue counting the elements from first column of next row, if that exists.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an array of 3-element arrays of integers. In contexts that expect a "pointer to foo", you can use an "array of foo" and it will behave like a pointer to its first element, so `*data` is a pointer to the first element of `data`, namely (so to speak) `{23,55,50}`.

So, the answer to the first question in the comments: No, it isn't true that `Ptr = 23`. (It couldn't be; `Ptr` is an `int *` and 23 is an `int`.)

You are correct that `Ptr = *(data+i)` makes `Ptr` point to the `i`th row of `data`. More precisely, `data` is an array of 3-element arrays of int, which behaves like a pointer to 3-element arrays of int; adding `i` to it moves past `i` such arrays.

The usual way to access other columns of the array is ordinary array indexing. If you refer to `data[i][j]`, you're getting column `j` of row `i`. If you want to do it with explicit pointer arithmetic, then note that (e.g.) `Ptr` in the example code is of type "pointer to integer", so `Ptr+1` (for instance) is element 1 of whatever row `Ptr` is pointing to. (But, as a matter of style, you should generally not do explicit pointer arithmetic when you don't actually need to.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example the loop goes through all matrix rows to find the one whose sum of all elements holds the maximum value.

At the beginning a pointer to the first row is assigned:

```
Ptr = *data;
```

Which means that the following is true:

```
(Ptr[0] == 23 && Ptr[1] == 55 && Ptr[2] == 50)
```

Notice that **Ptr** is a pointer so it holds a memory address, hence **Ptr** is different than **23** (unless the memory address happens to be **23**, which is unlikely to happen).

Answer (score 0):

C allows multidimensional arrays, lays them out in memory as contiguous locations, and does more behind the scenes address arithmetic.
Consider a 2-dimensional array.

```c
int arr[ 3 ][ 3 ] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

The compiler treats a 2 dimensional array as an array of arrays,
where an array name is a pointer to the first element within the array.
So, `arr` points to the first 3-element array, which is actually the first row (i.e., row 0) of the two-dimensional array.
Similarly, `(arr + 1)` points to the second 3-element array (i.e., row 1) and so on.
The value of this pointer, `*(arr + 1)`, refers to the entire row.
Since row 1 is a one-dimensional array, `(arr + 1)` is actually a pointer to the first element in row 1.
Now add 2 to this pointer. Hence, `(*(arr + 1) + 2)` is a pointer to element 2 (i.e., the third element) in row 1. The value of this expression, `*(*(arr + 1) + 2)`, is the value of the element in column 2 of row 1.