# Pointer assignment conceptual mental block: Ptr = *array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, variable-assignment

After reading this:
[2D array and pointer in C - how to access elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177410/2d-array-and-pointer-in-c-how-to-access-elements/11177870)

I'm still confused about the 'Ptr = *data' not being a de-reference.

Relevant code from that question:

```
int data[4][3] = { {23,55,50},{45,38,55},{70,43,45},{34,46,60}};
int *Ptr;

Ptr = *data;   //  This is not a de-reference.  Ptr is not 23.  Why?
```

I don't understand this on a conceptual level. I the see ' * ' and I think
de-reference.

Saying Ptr = *(data + 0), doesn't help, to me it still means de-reference
and we end up de-referencing the address 'data'.

Can anyone shed some light and help me understand?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: C  does not have 2D arrays.  `data` is a 1D array, where each element is a 1D array of ints.

Comment: What makes you think `*data` is not a dereference?

Comment: @stark I think you mean it has two forms of 2D arrays, one where it's contiguous, another where it's an array of pointers to other arrays.

Comment: @tadman, although I'm not sure I would agree with stark that C arrays of arrays should not be characterized as "2D arrays", I do generally take the position that arrays of pointers should not be characterized that way.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Although there's an infinite amount of room for pedantry here, `a[x][y]` is arguably a 2D array structure regardless of the implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*data` is technically a dereference, but, as we will see, it does not actually cause an access to the object it references.

`data` is an array of arrays. When an array is used in an expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, except when it is used as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array. In `*data`, this conversion effectively changes `data` to `&data[0]`, which is a pointer to the first array of `data`.

Since `&data[0]` is a pointer to the first array, `*data` is that array. So, we have dereferenced `&data[0]` to get the array it references.

However, since `*data` is an array, it is also automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So, instead of `*data` causing an access to the array, it is changed to `&(*data)[0]`. With the first conversion included, that is `&(*&data[0])[0]`. Then, removing the self-canceling `*&`, that is `&(data[0])[0]` or just `&data[0][0]`.

So `*data` is `&data[0][0]`, the address of the first element of the first array of `data`.

Comment: ***`it does not actually cause an access to the object it references`*** it does. But it references 3 elements int array. That derefenced array when used as pointer decals to `int *`, so additional dereference needed

Answer (score 2):

`data` is two-dimensional array and decals to `int (*)[3]` pointer.
`*data` is three elements `int` array and decals to `int *` pointer.

`Ptr` contains a reference to the first element of that int[3] array which is 23.

You need to dereference this pointer to get the integer `23`

```
int main(void)
{
    int data[4][3] = { {23,55,50},{45,38,55},{70,43,45},{34,46,60}};
    int *ptr;

    ptr = *data;   //  This is not a de-reference.  Ptr is not 23.  Why?

    printf("%d\n", *ptr);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

Let's draw out the array with its values, showing the address of each element.  For this diagram we're assuming 4-byte `int`s and the addresses are made up out of thin air:

```
Address      Value    Expression                  
-------      +----+   ----------
 0x4000      | 23 |   data[0][0] 
             + -- +
 0x4004      | 55 |   data[0][1]
             + -- +
 0x4008      | 50 |   data[0][2]
             +----+
 0x400c      | 45 |   data[1][0]
             + -- +
 0x4010      | 38 |   data[1][1]
             + -- +
 0x4014      | 55 |   data[1][2]
             +----+
 0x4018      | 70 |   data[2][0]
             + -- +
 0x401c      | 43 |   data[2][1]
             + -- +
 0x4020      | 45 |   data[2][2]
             +----+
 0x4024      | 34 |   data[3][0]
             + -- +
 0x4028      | 46 |   data[3][1]
             + -- +
 0x402c      | 60 |   data[3][2]
             +----+
```

Now we can talk about the types of various expressions.

Let's start with the expression `data`.  As declared, the expression has type "4-element array of 3-element array of `int`" (`int [4][3]`).  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will "decay" to an expression of type "pointer to 3-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[3]`) and will evaluate to the address `0x4000`.

Next, we look at the expression `*data`.  We already know that `data` has type "pointer to 3-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[3]`), so by dereferencing it, we get an expression of type "3-element array of `int`" (`int [3]`).  Unless this expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will "decay" to type "pointer to `int`" (`int *`) and it will also evaluate to the address `0x4000`.

Now let's look at the expressions `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]`, and `data[3]`.  Remember that the array subscript expression `a[i]` is exactly equivalent to the expression `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (not bytes!) from that address and dereference the result.  Since `data` points to a 3-element array of `int`, `data + 1` will point to the next *3-element array of `int`*.  So if `data == 0x4000`, then `data + 1 == 0x400c`, `data + 2 == 0x4018`, and `data + 3 == 0x4024`.  Since `data[i] == *(data + i)`, the *type* of each `data[i]` will be `int [3]` (just like `*data` above, which is exactly equivalent to `data[0]` since `*data == *(data + 0) == data[0]`).

Hopefully each `data[i][j]` is obvious at this point - each `data[i]` has type `int [3]`, which "decays" to `int *`, and `data[i][j] == *(data[i] + j)`.

A few other expressions of note:

- `&data` has type "pointer to 4-element array of 3-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[4][3]`, and its value is also `0x4000` because the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element.
- Similarly, `&data[i]` has type "pointer to 3-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[3]`); like the expression above, the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element, so `&data[0] == data[0] == 0x4000`, `&data[1] == data[1] == 0x400c`, etc.

To summarize:

```
Expression        Type          "Decays" to        Value
----------        ----          -----------        ------
      data        int [4][3]    int (*)[3]         0x4000
     *data        int [3]       int *              0x4000
     &data        int (*)[4][3] n/a                0x4000
   data[i]        int [3]       int *              0x4000, 0x400c, 0x4018, 0x4024
  *data[i]        int           na/                23, 45, 70, 34
  &data[i]        int (*)[3]    n/a                0x4000, 0x400c, 0x4018, 0x4024
data[i][j]        int           n/a                23, 55, 50, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting another example, a complete C program, that may help to see the logic behind this

#### First, some details

> I'm still confused about the 'Ptr = *data' not being a de-reference.

Well, it is a de-reference, the `*` in an assignment is a de-reference in C. **BUT** `*data` is not `int`: it is `int[4][3]` and holds the **address** of the first element of the array, and it points to an `int` whose is `23`. One level of indirection was lost in your code.

```
      Ptr  is int*
     *Ptr  is an address, &data[0][0] or simply *data
    **Ptr  is 23
```

Key to understand this is the line

```
    Ptr = *data;
```

#### See what gcc says when compiling this:

```
toninho@DSK-2009:~/projects/dsp$ gcc -o tptr -Wall -Wextra -std=c17 tptr.c

tptr.c: In function ‘main’:
    tptr.c:19:9: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from\
 incompatible pointer type int (*)[4][3]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    19 |     Ptr = &data;
      |         ^
```

#### The Microsoft compiler says:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: sop-0328-a, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ptr.c
1>C:\Users\toninho\source\repos\sop-0328-a\sop-0328-a\ptr.c(19,20):
    warning C4047: '=': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (*)[4][3]'
1>sop-0328-a.vcxproj -> C:\Users\toninho\source\repos\sop-0328-a\Debug\sop-0328-a.exe
1>Done building project "sop-0328-a.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

#### clang compiler says:

```
C:\Users\toninho\source\repos\sop-0328-a\sop-0328-a>clang -Wall ptr.c
ptr.c:19:13: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning
 to 'int *' from 'int (*)[4][3]'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    Ptr = &data;
            ^ ~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

And it is the same. **You should always enable all warnings, on all compilers**.

> I don't understand this on a conceptual level. I the see ' * ' and I
> think de-reference.
>
> Saying Ptr = *(data + 0), doesn't help, to me it still means
> de-reference and we end up de-referencing the address 'data'.
>
> Can anyone shed some light and help me understand?

As I said, it is a de-reference. Problem is you passed a `int*[4][3]` to an `int*`, did not have the compiler warnings enabled and :) was not aware of this thing. Professionals do that all the time and sometimes get surprised too.
You should write `Ptr = (int*) *data;`

I believe the program below can show it better. Adding to 0 sure made no difference. You would need to add another `*`

Please see the code below and ask back if it is still not clear.

Note that at the end of the code the lines

```
    pointer = (int*) &many;
    printf("Using a cast 'pointer' now points to '(int*) many' \
and its value is %d\n", *pointer);
```

uses a cast and prints

```
Using a cast 'pointer' now points to '(int*) many' and its value is 23
```

and now he compiler is happy and the output is the expected 23

#### Example

The output of the program is

```
'one' is an int at address      00EFFDB4
'many'is int[4][3] at address   00EFFD7C
'pointer' is int* at address    00EFFDC0

'pointer' now points to 'one' and its value is  00EFFDB4
'pointer' now points to 'many' and its value is 00EFFD7C

'many' is a C array, a pointer pointing to the address  00EFFD7C ( &many[0][0] )
'many' content, an address, is  00EFFD7C ( *many )

Starting at this location --- 00EFFD7C ( *many ) --- we have the values of the array
First value is 23 ( **many ),
Second value is 55 ( *(1 + *many)... )
Usng a cast 'pointer' now points to '(int*) many' and its value is 23
```

And you can see the addresses on the debugger screen, along with the actual types of the variables (program stopped at line #23):

[image]

#### The code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int*    pointer = NULL;
    int     one = 1;
    int     many[4][3] =
    {
        {23,55,50},
        {45,38,55},
        {70,43,45},
        {34,46,60}
    };
    printf("'one' is an int at address\t%p\n", &one);
    printf("'many'is int[4][3] at address\t%p\n", &many);
    printf("'pointer' is int* at address\t%p\n\n", &pointer);
    pointer = &one;
    printf("'pointer' now points to 'one' and its value is\t%p\n", pointer);
    pointer = &many;
    printf("'pointer' now points to 'many' and its value is\t%p\n", pointer);
    printf("\n'many' is a C array, a pointer pointing to the address\t%p ( &many[0][0] )\n", &many[0][0]);
    printf("'many' content, an address, is\t%p ( *many )\n", *many);
    printf("\nStarting at this location --- %p ( *many ) --- we have the values of the array\n\
First value is %d ( **many ),\n\
Second value is %d ( *(1 + *many)... )\n", *many, **many, *(1 + *many) );

    pointer = (int*) &many;
    printf("Using a cast 'pointer' now points to '(int*) many' \
and its value is %d\n", *pointer);

    return 0;

}
```